# How to plot subfigures in a specific order (two columns)?

Tags: subfloats, ieeetran, subfig

I'm using the following class and package:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[caption=off]{subfig}
```

I'd like to know how to create the subfigure in the caption order as shown in the image attached.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a minipages and the `valign` option you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[caption=off]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width= 0.9\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image}}\\
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width= 0.9\linewidth]{example-image}}\\
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width= 0.9\linewidth]{example-image}}\\
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width= 0.9\linewidth,height=20cm,valign=t]{example-image}}\\
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{a caption for all the images}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I did some minor edits over your answer and it solved my problem. I think I wasn't clear about the two columns, but I actually wanted subfigures in two columns, so I removed the * from figure*. Also changed some widths to get what I needed. Thanks.